# passing angular running environment to gulp

Tags: angular, npm, gulp

I need to change the gulp destination path according to angular build environment.

gulpfile.js

```
var DIST_PATH = 'src/build'; // for local 
var DIST_PATH_PROD = 'dist';   // for production
```

npm scripts

```
"local": "concurrently --kill-others \"gulp watch\" \"ng serve\"",
"prod": "concurrently --kill-others \"gulp\" \"ng build --prod\"",
```

when I run `npm run prod`, is it possible to pass an argument to gulp mentioning that whether it is production or local?

Comment: Which version of angular are you using?

Comment: I'm using angular 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do it from a node module called `yargs`

```
npm install --save-dev yargs
```

and then I can send a flag like this

```
gulp default --production
```

and inside gulpfile I can access it.

```
var argv = require('yargs').argv;
var isProduction = (argv.production === undefined) ? false : true;
```